# How to take a screen shot of an app (within an app)? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, screenshot

So what if I want to make an app where you can take a screen shot within the app itself. How would I do that? So for example the users click a UIButton and it takes a picture of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an undocumented, but SDK allowed, function `UIGetScreenImage()`. It returns a `CGImage` that you are responsible for releasing yourself.

Comment: Hi,

What do you mean by SDK allowed ? Will the application be accepted by Apple ?

Regards,

Comment: That means allowed for the App Store, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to take screenshots? Or is there a reason you need to take a screenshot in the application itself?

Because on the iphone you can hit the power button and home button at the same time to take a screenshot (which is saved the to the camera roll).

Comment: I am trying to take a screenshot in the application itself.